# How does the skate work in backwards, front crossovers?

Tags: technique, skating, ice-skating

You are going backwards, with constant crossovers done in front. See here: [Hockey Powerskating / Edgework Circuit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YtwM1T3_x6M&feature=youtu.be&t=1m54s) (by m2hockey). I tried to recreate that move (and I failed), I barely moved backwards.

My current theory -- let's say I glide on left, and I am doing crossover with right. So left is on external edge, I do crossover, right is on internal edge. After crossover I go from internal edge to external, and then I do crossover with left.

However in this video it looks much simpler. What do I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh boy. Tough to describe. This move actually is entirely on the outside edge of your skate. Your power is going to come from cutting/steering the outside (external) edge around in a tight 'C'.

Although it looks like he is starting on his inside edge, he is just barely on the outside edge.

Don't over think it!